# Updating state array in react native

Tags: arrays, react-native, state, rendering, use-effect

I'm trying to keep track of a list of chosen exercises, and then render 'added' if the chosen exercise is in the list, or 'not added' if it's not in the list. I add the exercise to `chosenExerciseArray` when it's not already included, and remove it if it is. When I use `console.log(chosenExerciseArray)` it correctly displays the list, but if I use `setChosenExercises(chosenExerciseArray)` the state does not get updated correctly, and the `chosenExerciseArray` somehow stops logging the correct array as well.

I've also tried adding `chosenExerciseArray` as a useEffect dependency, but that causes an infinite loop. I'm really not sure what's going on here, but I believe it's an issue with my understanding of state.

**EDIT:** The TouchableOpacity is inside of a map, which may also be the issue, but I'm not sure how

```
<View style={styles.exerciseheadericongroup}>
   <TouchableOpacity
       onPress={() => {
         if(!chosenExerciseArray.includes(exercise.id)) {
            chosenExerciseArray.push(exercise.id);
         } else {
            for(var i=0; i<chosenExerciseArray.length; i++) {
               if(chosenExerciseArray[i] === exercise.id) {
                 chosenExerciseArray.splice(i, 1);
               }
             }
          }
          console.log(chosenExerciseArray);
        }}
    >
    {chosenExercises.includes(exercise.id) ? (
       <Text>added</Text>
    ) : (
       <Text>not added</Text>
    )}
  </TouchableOpacity>
</View>
```

Answer (score 0):

As stated in the React documentation

> state is a reference to the component state at the time the change is being applied. It should not be directly mutated. Instead, changes should be represented by building a new object based on the input from state and props. [[link]](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html)

I wish I could explain it better, but basically it means that manipulating `chosenExerciseArray` with `.push` and then executing `setChosenExerciseArray(chosenExerciseArray)` messes up the state handling. You need to make a copy of `chosenExerciseArray` and manipulate it instead, and then use the manipulated copy to set the new state. I have created two examples for you to look at:

**Example 1** uses a different logic, where `added` is part of the exercise object itself, such that that the `chosenExerciseArray` is not necessary to keep track of whether the exercise is added or not. This is also a bit more efficient, because you do not need to check if an exercise is in the `chosenExerciseArray` or not.

```js
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { Pressable, StyleSheet } from "react-native";

import { Text, View } from "../components/Themed";

interface Exercise {
  id: string;
  name: string;
  added: boolean;
}

const updateExerciseArray = (exercises: Exercise[], exercise: Exercise) => {
  // Shallow copy
  const updatedExercises = [...exercises];

  // Manipulate the copy
  return updatedExercises.map((updatedExercise) => {
    if (updatedExercise.id === exercise.id) {
      // Shallow copy of object in array where added is negated
      return { ...updatedExercise, added: !updatedExercise.added };
    }
    return updatedExercise;
  });
};

export default function Example1() {
  const [exercises, setExercises] = useState<Exercise[]>([
    { id: "1", name: "Pushups", added: false },
    { id: "2", name: "Situps", added: false },
    { id: "3", name: "Squats", added: false },
    { id: "4", name: "Pullups", added: false },
    { id: "5", name: "Leg Raises", added: false },
    { id: "6", name: "Plank", added: false },
    { id: "7", name: "Burpees", added: false },
    { id: "8", name: "Jumping Jacks", added: false },
    { id: "9", name: "Wall Sit", added: false },
  ]);

  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      {exercises.map((exercise) => {
        return (
          <Pressable
            key={exercise.id}
            onPress={() => {
              setExercises(updateExerciseArray(exercises, exercise));
            }}
            style={styles.row}
          >
            <Text style={styles.text}>{exercise.name}</Text>
            <Text style={styles.text}>
              {exercise.added ? "Added" : "Not added"}
            </Text>
          </Pressable>
        );
      })}
    </View>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    paddingHorizontal: 50,
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: "#fff",
    justifyContent: "center",
  },
  row: {
    marginVertical: 10,
    flexDirection: "row",
    justifyContent: "space-between",
  },
  text: {
    fontSize: 20,
  },
});
```

**Example 2** uses a solution that fits your current implementation.

```js
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { Pressable, StyleSheet } from "react-native";

import { Text, View } from "../components/Themed";

interface Exercise {
  id: string;
  name: string;
}

const updateExerciseArray = (
  chosenExerciseArray: string[],
  exerciseToChange: Exercise
) => {
  // Shallow copy
  const updatedChosenExerciseArray = [...chosenExerciseArray];

  if (updatedChosenExerciseArray.includes(exerciseToChange.id)) {
    // Remove the exercise from the array
    return updatedChosenExerciseArray.filter(
      (exerciseId) => exerciseId !== exerciseToChange.id
    );
  } else {
    // Append the exercise to the array
    return [...updatedChosenExerciseArray, exerciseToChange.id];
  }
};

export default function Example2() {
  const [exercises] = useState<Exercise[]>([
    { id: "1", name: "Pushups" },
    { id: "2", name: "Situps" },
    { id: "3", name: "Squats" },
    { id: "4", name: "Pullups" },
    { id: "5", name: "Leg Raises" },
    { id: "6", name: "Plank" },
    { id: "7", name: "Burpees" },
    { id: "8", name: "Jumping Jacks" },
    { id: "9", name: "Wall Sit" },
  ]);
  const [chosenExerciseArray, setChosenExerciseArray] = useState<string[]>([
    "1",
    "2",
  ]);

  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      {exercises.map((exercise) => {
        return (
          <Pressable
            key={exercise.id}
            onPress={() => {
              setChosenExerciseArray(
                updateExerciseArray(chosenExerciseArray, exercise)
              );
            }}
            style={styles.row}
          >
            <Text style={styles.text}>{exercise.name}</Text>
            <Text style={styles.text}>
              {chosenExerciseArray.includes(exercise.id)
                ? "Added"
                : "Not added"}
            </Text>
          </Pressable>
        );
      })}
    </View>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    paddingHorizontal: 50,
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: "#fff",
    justifyContent: "center",
  },
  row: {
    paddingVertical: 10,
    flexDirection: "row",
    justifyContent: "space-between",
  },
  text: {
    fontSize: 20,
  },
});
```